# Print items from text file with \n delimiter to a CSV file

Tags: bash, csv

I have a file that has a few lines printed as follows:

```
               username: no_way
               EMAILID: some@email.com
               enc_username: DEFAULT
               MACHINE_CODE: 
               FIRSTNAME: John
               LASTNAME: Doe
               ACCOUNT_STATUS: Y
```

I want to capture username:, EMAILID:, FIRSTNAME: and LASTNAME: and print those in a CSV file that has:

```
no_way,some@email.com,john,doe
```

...on each row.

I tried using:

```
cat file | egrep 'ACCOUNT_STATUS:\ Y' &  egrep 'EMAILID:' & egrep 'username:' >> newfile
```

But, this doesn't work. I realized it is because the | pipe filters only that single line and since these are on separate lines, this will not work.

Then, I tried just changing the delimiters:

```
tr -dc '\n' ',' file | tee newfile
```

But, this gave me an error whether I used '-dc' or any options whatsoever.

What do I need to do to take these lines and put them in a CSV file?

I am using bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using awk

```
$ awk '$1 ~ /^(username:|EMAILID:|FIRSTNAME:)$/{printf "%s,",$2} $1 ~ /LASTNAME:/{print $2}' file
no_way,some@email.com,John,Doe
```

#### How it works

- `$1 ~ /^(username:|EMAILID:|FIRSTNAME:)$/{printf "%s,",$2}`

  If the first field matches one of `username:`, `EMAILID:`, or `FIRSTNAME:`, then print the second field followed by a comma.
- `$1 ~ /LASTNAME:/{print $2}'`

  If the first field matches `LASTNAME:`, then print the second field followed by a newline.

### Using bash

```
while read key value
do
    case "$key" in 
        username:|EMAILID:|FIRSTNAME:) printf "%s," "$value";;
        LASTNAME:) printf "%s\n" "$value";;
    esac
done <file
```

This produces the output:

```
no_way,some@email.com,John,Doe
```